# Defining Covariance and showing a special case

Tags: probability

If $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables, define the covariance $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$ and show that $\mathrm{Cov}(aX+b,Y)=a\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$.

So I define the covariance as Cov$\displaystyle(X,Y)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^N\frac{(x_i-\mu_x )(y_i-\mu_y)}{N}$ where $N$ is the sample size. How would I show that $\mathrm{Cov}(aX+b,Y)=a\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$?

Answer (score 2):

The usual definition of covariance of random variables $S$ and $T$ is $E((S-\mu_S)(T-\mu_T))$, where $\mu_S=E(S)$ and $\mu_T=E(T)$. This  is easily shown to be equal to $E(ST)-\mu_S\mu_T$. We can use either version in the  proof.

Let $S=aX+b$ and $T=Y$. Note that $\mu_S=a\mu_X+b$ and $\mu_T=\mu_Y$. Thus
$$\text{Cov}(S,T)=E((aX+b-a\mu_X-b)(Y-\mu_Y))=aE((X-\mu_X)(Y--\mu_Y))=a\text{Cov}(X,Y).$$